# How to pass method arguments to a selector

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, methods, arguments, selector

If I have a method like this:

```
- (void) foo
{
}
```

Then I can access it through a selector like this:

```
@selector(foo)
```

But what if I have a method like this:

```
- (void) bar:(NSString *)str arg2:(NSString *)str2
{

}
```

Then how do I access it through a selector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To handle an arbitrary number of selectors you should use `NSInvocation`, but you can handle up to two objects using the standard performWithSelector stuff

`[foo performSelector:@selector(bar:arg2:) withObject:obj1 withObject:obj2]`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the spaces, parameter types, and parameter names. In your example, this would become:

```
@selector(bar:arg2:)
```

Comment: Then how do you pass the parameters?

Comment: See Joshua's answer for how to invoke the selector.