# selector for a method with multiple parameters

Tags: iphone, selector, uitoolbar

Hi all I need to write selector for this method. How can I do it? Thanx!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Here is the code where I need it:

```
UIBarButtonItem *deleteButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Delete User" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(my_button_click_here_is_need_a_selector:)];

[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: deleteButton, nil]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to pass method arguments to a selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878696/how-to-pass-method-arguments-to-a-selector) on how to create a selector for that method (the answer is `@selector(tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`).

But you are using the `-initWithTitle:…` method wrongly if you pass this selector. The `action`'s selector must be a callback in the one of the forms

```
-(IBAction)clicked;
-(IBAction)clicked:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)clicked:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent*)event;
```

the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is none of the above. You should write a specific method for it.